# How to best represent selectable items in a collection within the M-V-VM design pattern?

Tags: wpf, design-patterns, collections, mvvm, selection

I'm just beginning to explore the M-V-VM design pattern while redeveloping an application and I'm running across a consistent theme where I have collections that I need my ViewModel to expose to the View which contain items which are to be selected by the user. Please note that when I say "selected" what I mean is that they are chosen in some permanent manner such as with check boxes within a grid control and not necessary highlighted like in a regular list box control. So far I have two different ideas of how this could be implemented and I want to know whether there are any thoughts about which way is the best to go about this.

1. Expose two separate collections, one representing a read-only copy of available items and another which holds a subset of items which are contained within the first collection and represents those of the available items which are current selected.
2. Expose a single collection through my ViewModel but make that collection a specialized collection that in some way tracks which items of the collection are selected. An example of this methodology can be found in [this article](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/ViewModels_and_CheckListBoxes.aspx) by Josh Twist.

I do realize that option 2 is really just a modification of option 1 except for that the two collections are managed as one unit. I'm more interested knowing which ways have been proven successful in terms of manageability, performance, and effective data binding within WPF.

I've also come across an article on [How to Databind to a SelectedItems property in WPF](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2009/02/how-to-databind-to-selecteditems.html) as well as another one which details how to [Sync Multi Select Listbox with ViewModel](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2009/06/02/sync-multi-select-listbox-with-viewmodel/). After reading the different methodologies out there I realize that this may not be something that M-V-VM practitioners have a reached a consensus on however I'm hoping I can limit the field a bit without trying each one and comparing.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Previously there was a link to an article by Josh Smith but it's broken currently.

However, now I make use of a [SelectionViewModel](http://nanomvvm.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/9cceda3d01af#Source/Main/NanoMvvm/ViewModels/Common/Selection/SelectionViewModel.cs) and some other helper classes in the [NanoMVVM](http://nanomvvm.codeplex.com/) library.

The library is not for production use (yet) but there may be stuff of use there, including a running sample of MVVM selection with different selection modes.

Answer (score 0):

[PRISM MVVM Reference Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405492%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx) has a behaviour called SynchronizeSelectedItems, used in Prism4\MVVM RI\MVVM.Client\Views\MultipleSelectionView.xaml, which synchronizes checked items with the ViewModel property named `Selections`:

```
        <ListBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" IsTabStop="False" SelectionMode="Multiple"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Question.Range}" Margin="5">

            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <!-- Custom style to show the multi-selection list box as a collection of check boxes -->
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                              IsHitTestVisible="False" IsTabStop="True"
                                              AutomationProperties.AutomationId="CheckBoxAutomationId">
                                        <ContentPresenter/>
                                    </CheckBox>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <!-- Custom behavior that synchronizes the selected items with the view models collection -->
                <Behaviors:SynchronizeSelectedItems Selections="{Binding Selections}"/>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </ListBox>
```

Go to http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/ and grab it all or use this:

```
//===================================================================================
// Microsoft patterns & practices
// Composite Application Guidance for Windows Presentation Foundation and Silverlight
//===================================================================================
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
// THIS CODE AND INFORMATION IS PROVIDED "AS IS" WITHOUT WARRANTY
// OF ANY KIND, EITHER EXPRESSED OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT
// LIMITED TO THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND
// FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
//===================================================================================
// The example companies, organizations, products, domain names,
// e-mail addresses, logos, people, places, and events depicted
// herein are fictitious.  No association with any real company,
// organization, product, domain name, email address, logo, person,
// places, or events is intended or should be inferred.
//===================================================================================
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;

namespace MVVM.Client.Infrastructure.Behaviors
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Custom behavior that synchronizes the list in <see cref="ListBox.SelectedItems"/> with a collection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This behavior uses a weak event handler to listen for changes on the synchronized collection.
    /// </remarks>
    public class SynchronizeSelectedItems : Behavior<ListBox>
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectionsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "Selections",
                typeof(IList),
                typeof(SynchronizeSelectedItems),
                new PropertyMetadata(null, OnSelectionsPropertyChanged));

        private bool updating;
        private WeakEventHandler<SynchronizeSelectedItems, object, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs> currentWeakHandler;

        [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly",
            Justification = "Dependency property")]
        public IList Selections
        {
            get { return (IList)this.GetValue(SelectionsProperty); }
            set { this.SetValue(SelectionsProperty, value); }
        }

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();

            this.AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += this.OnSelectedItemsChanged;
            this.UpdateSelectedItems();
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            this.AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += this.OnSelectedItemsChanged;

            base.OnDetaching();
        }

        private static void OnSelectionsPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var behavior = d as SynchronizeSelectedItems;

            if (behavior != null)
            {
                if (behavior.currentWeakHandler != null)
                {
                    behavior.currentWeakHandler.Detach();
                    behavior.currentWeakHandler = null;
                }

                if (e.NewValue != null)
                {
                    var notifyCollectionChanged = e.NewValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
                    if (notifyCollectionChanged != null)
                    {
                        behavior.currentWeakHandler =
                            new WeakEventHandler<SynchronizeSelectedItems, object, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>(
                                behavior,
                                (instance, sender, args) => instance.OnSelectionsCollectionChanged(sender, args),
                                (listener) => notifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged -= listener.OnEvent);
                        notifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged += behavior.currentWeakHandler.OnEvent;
                    }

                    behavior.UpdateSelectedItems();
                }
            }
        }

        private void OnSelectedItemsChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.UpdateSelections(e);
        }

        private void UpdateSelections(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.ExecuteIfNotUpdating(
                () =>
                {
                    if (this.Selections != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var item in e.AddedItems)
                        {
                            this.Selections.Add(item);
                        }

                        foreach (var item in e.RemovedItems)
                        {
                            this.Selections.Remove(item);
                        }
                    }
                });
        }

        private void OnSelectionsCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.UpdateSelectedItems();
        }

        private void UpdateSelectedItems()
        {
            this.ExecuteIfNotUpdating(
                () =>
                {
                    if (this.AssociatedObject != null)
                    {
                        this.AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Clear();
                        foreach (var item in this.Selections ?? new object[0])
                        {
                            this.AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Add(item);
                        }
                    }
                });
        }

        private void ExecuteIfNotUpdating(Action execute)
        {
            if (!this.updating)
            {
                try
                {
                    this.updating = true;
                    execute();
                }
                finally
                {
                    this.updating = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I actually started writing something somewhat similar using Attached Properties about a month ago. I've stabilized my code a lot but so far the performance doesn't look good stacked up against the mini-ViewModel for each item approach. This is especially true for large bound ItemsSources using virtualization. I'll give this behavior a glance though, thanks for suggesting it.

Comment: There is a bug in the Microsoft's code above. It has this.AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged **+=** this.OnSelectedItemsChanged; in the OnDetaching() method. **+=** must be changed to **-=** to fix it.